# Two Tail Hypothesis Test with Variance

Tags: statistics

test the hypothesis the variance for economists equal the variance for the historians.  Use a .05 significance level, a two tail test and the following data :

```
     economist  historian
var     120       90
n        46       38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the F-test (Snedecor and Cochran, 1983) to test

$H_0: \sigma^2_{1} = \sigma^{2}_2$

versus

$H_A: \sigma^2_{1} \neq \sigma^{2}_2$

The $F$ statistics is obtained by $F = \sigma^2_1/\sigma^{2}_2$, with $\sigma^2_{1} \geq \sigma^{2}_{2}$ without loss of generality. In this case $F = 1.333$.

We must compare this value with the critical value from the table $F_{1-\alpha/2,N_1-1,N_2-1}= F_{0.975,45,37}=1.88$. The evaluated $F$ is smaller than critical $F$, so you don't reject $H_0$.